# Simple app: comma delimiter with input and output text boxes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, delimiter

All,

I'm looking to create a simple app that takes text entered by the user and splits it up, based on what line the text is entered on (it's a multiline textbox) using a comma.  It inserts this new comma-delimited value into an output textbox for the user.

I know this may be an embarrassingly easy question, but my VB is very rusty:
Is there a built-in VB function that can do this without the use of txt files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: VBA or VB.Net? You've tagged both.

Comment: Sorry, VB.Net.  I accidentally tagged VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, ",")
End Sub
```

Comment: That works!  Another question: what if I also want to add a single quote around each line entry?  So the output would look like this:

'1','2','3','4','5'

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out:

`Me.Output.Text = "('" & Input.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, "','") & "')"`

Thanks again!

Comment: You bet! Happy New Year.